# How To Rotate the screen After Pushing a new page From code in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, youtube, youtube-api

The Title says it pretty much, i'm pushing a WebView that contains VideoSource
Witch have a youtube Video embed HTML code.
And i need to force it into full screen mode once its pushed.
this is a Piece of the code i'm using if you have any other/better way to do it please answer

i'm a newbie so please go easy on me :)

i search for a bit on this subject but i cant find anyway to rotate the screen on only 1 page when its pushed.

```
    public partial class MainScreen : TabbedPage
    {
        public HtmlWebViewSource VideoSource { get; set; }

        private const string PlayerHTML = @"<html>
             <body>  
             <iframe style='position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;'  
             src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/6e7qKcVigQo?rel=0?autoplay=1?modestbranding=1' 
             frameborder='0' 
             allow='accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture' 
             allowfullscreen>
             </iframe>
             </body>
             </html>";

        private async void ImageButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            VideoSource = new HtmlWebViewSource
            {
                Html = PlayerHTML
            };

            var a = new ContentPage
            {
                Content = new WebView()
                {

                    Source = VideoSource
                }
            };
            NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(a, false);
            await Navigation.PushAsync(a);
            //make the screen rotate SOMEHOW
        }
    }
```

I expect 2 kinds of solutions;

1. Xamarin related solution like rotating the screen by reaching the MainActivity.cs
2. A HTML/YouTube Embed Solution like something in the Video Link to force start the video on full screen...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Messaging Center to handle that
on Android :

```
   protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        Current = this;
        //TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
        ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);

        //allowing the device to change the screen orientation based on the rotation
        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<VideoPlayerView>(this, "allowLandScape", sender =>
        {
            RequestedOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Landscape;
        });

        //during page close setting back to portrait
        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<VideoPlayerView>(this, "preventLandScape", sender =>
        {
            RequestedOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait;
        });

        LoadApplication(new App());
    }
```

for call that

```
   protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        MessagingCenter.Send(this, "allowLandScape");

    }

    //during page close setting back to portrait
    protected override void OnDisappearing()
    {
        base.OnDisappearing();
        MessagingCenter.Send(this, "preventLandScape");

    }
```